# Несколько VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: регулярные-выражения, apache2, поддомены

Хотелось бы в *apache2* настроить конфигурацию поддоменов по маске.

Это так и должно остаться

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.ru
    ServerAlias www.site.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Поддомены, имеющие вид *u+любая_цифра*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.ru
    ServerAlias ([u0-9]+).site.ru
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/public_html/users/%1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Конкретный поддомен:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.ru
    ServerAlias abc.site.ru
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/public_html/abc
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

У меня не работает, все поддомены направляют на основной.

Что нужно сделать? И можно ли это как то упростить/объединить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `regexp`-ы не поддерживаются в директиве `serveralias`. можно использовать только *wildcard* символы `*` и `?`: [wildcard characters * and ? can be used to match names](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html#using)
2. директива `servername` необязательна внутри блока `virtualhost`.
3. поиск подходящего блока `virtualhost` осуществляется последовательно, используется первый подходящий.

пример:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  serveralias u?.d
  redirect 301 / /1
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:80>
  serveralias u*.d
  redirect 301 / /2
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:80>
  serveralias u??.d
  redirect 301 / /3
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:80>
  serveralias ??.d
  redirect 301 / /4
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:80>
  serveralias *.d
  redirect 301 / /5
</virtualhost>
```

обращения к `uu.d` попадут в первый из блоков (квантификатор `?` означает «один какой-нибудь символ»):

```
$ wget -S --spider --header "host: uu.d" http://localhost 2>&1 | grep -i ' location'
  Location: http://uu.d/1
```

а обращения к `uuu.d` попадут не в третий, а во второй блок: квантификатор `*` означает «ноль или больше символов». туда же попадут и обращения к `u.d` (собственно, до третьего блока вообще никак не «добраться»):

```
$ wget -S --spider --header "host: uuu.d" http://localhost 2>&1 | grep -i ' location'
  Location: http://uuu.d/2
$ wget -S --spider --header "host: u.d" http://localhost 2>&1 | grep -i ' location'
  Location: http://u.d/2
```

а в четвёртый блок попадут все обращения из двух букв в первой части имени, если первая буква — не `u`:

```
$ wget -S --spider --header "host: zz.d" http://localhost 2>&1 | grep -i ' location'
  Location: http://zz.d/4
$ wget -S --spider --header "host: z1.d" http://localhost 2>&1 | grep -i ' location'
  Location: http://z1.d/4
```

ну а в пятый блок — уже всё, что не подошло ни к одному из предыдущих:

```
$ wget -S --spider --header "host: xyz.d" http://localhost 2>&1 | grep -i ' location'
  Location: http://xyz.d/5
```

---

а директива `virtualdocumentroot` имеет смысл (и только тем и отличается от `documentroot`) лишь при использовании частей из доменного имени для распределения сайтов по каталогам. т.е., без вставок вида `%1` и т.п. она полностью идентична директиве `documentroot`.

смотрите официальную [документацию](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) и частичный [перевод](http://www.softtime.ru/info/apache.php?id_article=103).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, очень информативно