# Хост apache на 192.168.0.2 не видит

Tags: ubuntu, apache, сервер

Настроил виртуальные хосты на сервере по адресу 127.0.0.1 все сайты доступны, а по адресу 192.168.0.2 открывается дефолтная заглушка apache. 
Этот адрес я использую для веб морды vmbox. Все сайты открываю из внешней сети. Стоит Ubuntu server 14.04.

конфиг /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost loc.server
127.0.1.1       shamansrv
127.0.1.1       site1.server www.site1.server
127.0.1.1       site2.server www.site2.server
192.168.0.2     v.server www.v.server
192.168.0.1     m1.server
```

конфиг /etc/apache2/sites-available/v.conf

```
#ServerName shamansrv

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2:18083>

        ServerName v.server
        ServerAlias v.server www.v.server
        DocumentRoot /www/phpvirtualbox-4.3-3/

        ErrorLog /www/error.log
        CustomLog /www/access.log combined
        <Directory /www/phpvirtualbox-4.3-3/>
                Require all granted
                Require all denied
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Вывод команды

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
итого 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 янв.  12  2015 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 дек.   6  2014 site1.conf -> ../sites-available/site1.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 янв.   9  2015 site2.conf -> ../sites-available/site2.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 июня  17 11:56 v.conf -> ../sites-available/v.conf
```

К хосту стучусь так:
На удалённой машине пишу v.server на ней же настроен файл hosts

```
62.1xx.17x.xxx   site1.server www.site1.server
62.1xx.17x.xxx   site2.server www.site2.server
62.1xx.17x.xxx   loc.server m1.server v.server
```

Это адресс маршрутизатора, за ним на локальном адресе находится сам сервер 192.168.0.102. Сайты работают.

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. / информация [в помощь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437250/178576).

Comment: а открываете как? просто 192.168.0.2? Так у вас там порт надо дополнительно указывать, т.е. открывать 192.168.0.2:18083

Comment: поправил вопрос. порты на маршрутизаторе открыты

Comment: @shaman888, спасибо за выложенный листинг. значит, есть и другие включенные сайты. я бы порекомендовал для теста отключить остальные конфигурации: `sudo sh -c "a2dissite 000-default; a2dissite site1; a2dissite site2; apachectl reload"`. если после этого заработает, разбираться надо с содержимым этих отключенных файлов. p.s. включается сайт командой a2ensite.

Comment: @shaman888, тут уже больше чем один комментатор подключился, поэтому, чтобы я получил уведомление об ответе, упомяните меня явно.

Comment: @shaman888, «разбираться с содержимым» проще будет, включая сайты по одному: `sudo sh -c "a2ensite ...; apachectl reload"`. и смотрите, после включения какого из них работать перестанет. скорее всего, это будет именно `000-default`. тогда приведите его содержимое.

Comment: @shaman888: *сам сервер 192.168.0.102* — а в конфиге другой ip-адрес: 192.168.0.2

Comment: Пишу всем поменял все ip на локальный адрес сервера и в настройках апача убрал ip, порт стандартный 80. Перейти на хост могу, но вебморда виртуалки не проводит авторизацию. Хотя это уже другая история.

Comment: @ВОРОН я так делал, сайт был не доступен